# Multidimensional lookup against a range

Tags: excel

I have been searching for awhile but was unable to find anything to help solve my problem so figured I would try posting on here for help!

I have attached an image of the table I am working with

[image: table]

Basically I want to be able to query this table by saying I have a value of 36 months (column c) and the sales value is 25000 (row 5) so the answer is C5 (25)

The only answer I can come up with a massive amount of if statements.

Thanks!

Comment: It's easy if you transform column A into two columns. This way the low vale of the range would be in column A and the high value of the range would be in column B. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a basic 2-way range lookup if you can transform column A into two columns. If you cannot it becomes very messy.

Take a look at this image:

[image]

The formula to do what you want with the data organized as in the image is this:

```
=INDEX(1:1048576,MATCH($C$9,A:A,1),MATCH($C$10,1:1,1))
```

Comment: @ChrisCondy Were you able to get this going?

Answer (score 0):

You can use INDEX and MATCH combination.